# Realizar un query en Spring boot y Oracle 11g

Tags: spring-boot, oracle-11g, spring-mvc, spring-tool-suite

A continuación les presento el código del problema que e tenido y no lo puedo solucionar, el query esta bien quizás sea el código pero no puedo identificar el error.

Tengo mi Modelo : `Distancia`

```
@Entity
public class Distancia {

    @Id
    @Column
    private String codigo_estacion;

    @Column
    private String lat;

    @Column
    private String lng;

    @Column
    private Double distance;

    public Distancia() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public String getCodigo_estacion() {
        return codigo_estacion;
    }

    public void setCodigo_estacion(String codigo_estacion) {
        this.codigo_estacion = codigo_estacion;
    }

    public String getLat() {
        return lat;
    }

    public void setLat(String lat) {
        this.lat = lat;
    }

    public String getLng() {
        return lng;
    }

    public void setLng(String lng) {
        this.lng = lng;
    }

    public Double getDistance() {
        return distance;
    }

    public void setDistance(Double distance) {
        this.distance = distance;
    }

}
```

Mi Interface: `IDistancia`

```
@Repository
public interface IDistancia extends CrudRepository<Distancia, Serializable> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT\r\n" + 
            "   CODIGO_ESTACION,\r\n" + 
            "   LAT,\r\n" + 
            "   LNG,\r\n" + 
            "   ACOS(\r\n" + 
            "       SIN(\r\n" + 
            "           RADIANS ( ?1 )) * SIN(\r\n" + 
            "           RADIANS ( LAT )) + COS(\r\n" + 
            "           RADIANS ( ?1 )) * COS(\r\n" + 
            "           RADIANS ( LAT )) * COS(\r\n" + 
            "       RADIANS ( ?2 ) - RADIANS ( LNG )) \r\n" + 
            "   ) * 6371 AS DISTANCE \r\n" + 
            "FROM\r\n" + 
            "   TB_ESTACION_PISCO\r\n" + 
            "WHERE \r\n" + 
            "(ACOS(\r\n" + 
            "       SIN(\r\n" + 
            "           RADIANS ( ?1 )) * SIN(\r\n" + 
            "           RADIANS ( LAT )) + COS(\r\n" + 
            "           RADIANS ( ?1 )) * COS(\r\n" + 
            "           RADIANS ( LAT )) * COS(\r\n" + 
            "       RADIANS ( ?2 ) - RADIANS ( LNG )) \r\n" + 
            "   ) * 6371) < 10 AND\r\n" + 
            "    rownum <= 1\r\n" + 
            "ORDER BY\r\n" + 
            "   DISTANCE ASC;", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Distancia> listarDistanciaAprox(String lat, String lng);

  
}
```

El resultado de mi query:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hasta ahí todo bien, pero cuando ejecuto , me sale el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: puedes mostrar el error completo, y en texto?
más allá de que los \r\n no son necesarios, creo que son considerados como espacios por lo que a primera vista no veo nada mal en tu query.

Comment: Lo mejor es ver todo el error como texto, revisando la documentación de la función RADIANS veo que recibe number  `RADIANS ( number )`, prueba cambiar tus variables `lat y lng` a double o float.

Comment: Ya tienes bastante rep. Deberías tener clarisisisisísimo que las cosas se comparten como texto. Copiar y pegar. :)

Answer (score 0):

en la interfaz que tienes definida, debes hacer lo siguiente

```
@Repository
public interface IDistancia extends CrudRepository<Distancia, String>
```

Ya que el @Id es de tipo String.

Valida a ver si es la causa.

Comment: Sería conveniente que explicaras el razonamiento detrás de tu respuesta. La clase String implementa Serializable.

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html

Comment: El ID en CrudRepocitory es herencia de Serializable, dejo la documentación de referencia.